# Разложение функции от двух переменных в ряд Тейлора

Tags: matlab

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Matlab раскладывать функцию в ряд Тейлора от двух переменных?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так (пакет Symbolic Math Toolbox должен быть установлен):

```
syms x y                      % x и y - объекты класса sym 
f = sin(x*y);                 % функция, которую раскладываем
taylor(f,[x y],'Order',15)    % до 15 порядка
```